# Неизвестный елемент, как сделать и где найти)

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
КАК НАЗЫВАЕТСЯ ТАКОЙ ЭЛЕМЕНТ, ИЛИ ПОДСКАЖИТЕ, ГДЕ ВЗЯТЬ ТАКОЙ ПЛАГИН ОЧЕНЬ ГОРИТ.

Comment: `slider`. куча плагинов для Jquery и т.д.

Comment: всм слайдер, это не похоже на слайдер)

Comment: это разновидность слайдера, ищите range slider

Comment: @dmitriyzubkov вам стоит прочесть правила https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Что у тебя горит?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Этот элемент управления называется **ползунок** или **слайдер** (*по-английски Slider*). Довольно часто его реализацию можно видеть на базе популярной библиотеки jQuery. Вы можете поискать их в [списке плагинов на сайте jQuery](https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/slider/) и найти подходящий, однако, если вы ее не используете, то можете использовать слайдер без использования каких либо сторонних библиотек, например [noUiSlider](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/)

Answer (score -2):

nouislider - нет зависимостей от других библиотек, весит очень мало (10кб), умеет всё, настраивается хорошо.
https://refreshless.com/nouislider/
Использовал его в нескольких больших проектах.

Comment: кто и почему поставил минус? действительно очень толковый плагин с богатым api

Comment: ссылки нежелательны и их можно приводить лишь в качестве источника. опубликуйте в ответе пример того, что нужно автору

Comment: вопрос был где найти, я ответил на вопрос.по ссылке как раз источник того, что нужно.

Comment: @i.mskiy завтра ваша сслылка будет недоступна по какой-то причине, какая польза будет от Вашего ответа? Пожалуйста прочтите справку **[почему и как удаляются некоторые ответы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)**. А минус не мой.

Comment: у вас какие-то свои правила? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer
четко написано - ссылки приветствуются, но к ссылке добавляйте контекст

Comment: А какой **полезный** контекст Вы добавили ? Чтобы ответ был более полезным Вы можете добавить работоспособный пример. Таким образом, даже если ссылка со временем будет недоступна можно будет увидеть работоспособный пример. [Обсуждение по данному вопросу](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1805/191745). P.S.: русская справка тоже [есть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). P.P.S.: а можете ничего не делать, здесь демократия :)

Comment: Вроде нормальный ответ.

Comment: @Qwertiy когда же он стал нормальным? **1** - источник умер, здравствуй гугл? **2** - so работает по принципу вопрос-ответ. де-юре плохой вопрос - ответ. де-факто - плохой вопрос - плохой ответ. Почему - потому что как минимум нужно идти на другой сайт, который может уже не работать вместо того, чтобы посмотреть рабочий пример здесь, на ru.so. В ином случае давайте уже не будем разделять что хорошо и что плохо и допускать все ответы-ссылки, а потом будем тратить время и удалять битые ссылки. Николай дал хороший ответ касательно ответов-ссылок.

Comment: @Qwertiy Речь не идет о том, что ответ совсем плохой, но для полноценного ответа, ему не хватает работоспособного примера. Это личное мнение, члены общества могут быть с ним согласны или не согласны. На мой взгляд, по-хорошему, нужно создавать отдельные вопросы и в них публиковать все ссылки в одном общем ответе, как сейчас q/a по книгам.

Comment: @Alex: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1639/178988 +11-2 & https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2619/178988 +15-5.

Comment: @Qwertiy есть и другие ответы  https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1818/191745 +16/0 :) Ваша позиция понятна, мое мнение не изменилось, там где можно, нужно вставлять код примера, чтобы именно на самом ru.so было больше полезной информации.  С данным пожеланием вы вряд ли можете быть не согласны) P.S.: да, можно взять название плагина и идти в гугл. но... зачем тогда ru.so ?

Comment: @Alex, тот вопрос более общий, я привёл ссылки на более конкретные :)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69546/discussion-between-alex-and-qwertiy).